# How to reduce or have no spaces between bars in the plot along with the reduction of width of the bar(size of each bar probably all are of same size)

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I have plotted a simple bar graph having 3 bars and what should i do for having no spaces or reduce space between the bars in plot and also reduce the width at atime

i have tried bargap=0 for no space and it has reflected but if i use width=0 along with it ,at a time both are not reflected .My plot orientation is vertical

Comment: can't we get both bargap=0 and width reduced at a time?